# What's the reason for this struct's alignment?

Tags: c++, c, struct, memory-alignment, struct-member-alignment

In the Vulkan header `vulkan.h` there is a struct defined as

```
typedef struct VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR {
    VkStructureType                  sType;
    const void*                      pNext;
    VkSwapchainCreateFlagsKHR        flags;
    VkSurfaceKHR                     surface;
    uint32_t                         minImageCount;
    VkFormat                         imageFormat;
    VkColorSpaceKHR                  imageColorSpace;
    VkExtent2D                       imageExtent;
    uint32_t                         imageArrayLayers;
    VkImageUsageFlags                imageUsage;
    VkSharingMode                    imageSharingMode;
    uint32_t                         queueFamilyIndexCount;
    const uint32_t*                  pQueueFamilyIndices;
    VkSurfaceTransformFlagBitsKHR    preTransform;
    VkCompositeAlphaFlagBitsKHR      compositeAlpha;
    VkPresentModeKHR                 presentMode;
    VkBool32                         clipped;
    VkSwapchainKHR                   oldSwapchain;
} VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR;
```

I've used the following code to see each field's alignment (Visual Studio 2015)

```
    std::cout <<
        "sType: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, sType) << std::endl <<
        "pNext: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, pNext) << std::endl <<
        "flags: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, flags) << std::endl <<
        "surface: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, surface) << std::endl <<
        "minImageCount: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, minImageCount) << std::endl <<
        "imageFormat: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, imageFormat) << std::endl <<
        "imageColorSpace: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, imageColorSpace) << std::endl <<
        "imageExtent: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, imageExtent) << std::endl <<
        "imageArrayLayers: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, imageArrayLayers) << std::endl <<
        "imageUsage: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, imageUsage) << std::endl <<
        "imageSharingMode: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, imageSharingMode) << std::endl <<
        "queueFamilyIndexCount: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, queueFamilyIndexCount) << std::endl <<
        "pQueueFamilyIndices: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, pQueueFamilyIndices) << std::endl <<
        "preTransform: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, preTransform) << std::endl <<
        "compositeAlpha: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, compositeAlpha) << std::endl <<
        "presentMode: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, presentMode) << std::endl <<
        "clipped: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, clipped) << std::endl <<
        "oldSwapchain: " << offsetof(VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR, oldSwapchain) << std::endl <<
        std::endl;
```

And got these results

```
sType: 0
pNext: 8
flags: 16
surface: 24
minImageCount: 32
imageFormat: 36
imageColorSpace: 40
imageExtent: 44
imageArrayLayers: 52
imageUsageFlags: 56
imageSharingMode: 60
queueFamilyIndexCount: 64
pQueueFamilyIndices: 72
preTransform: 80
compositeAlpha: 84
presentMode: 88
clipped: 92
oldSwapchain: 96
```

Between the fields `flags` and `surface` there is an 8 byte gap, even though `flags` has an underlying type of `uint32_t`. The same is true with the fields `queueFamilyIndexCount` and `pQueueFamilyIndices`. Why do `flags` and `queueFamilyIndexCount` take up 8 bytes when they are only 4 bytes wide and every other field of type `uint32_t` takes up only 4 bytes? Is there something special about the memory alignment requirements at those offsets?

Comment: Padding .........................

Comment: But why do only those fields get padded? Both of them are offset by multiple of 16, so why would the next field need padding?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He, nice. :)

Comment: It's about alignment to 64 bit addresses that will be better achieved for being accessed with the CPU's chache line.

Comment: The offset of a field depends on it's type, and where the previous field ends; not the type of the previous field.

Comment: I understand that. Every other `uint32_t` field only takes up 4 bytes and is not padded.

Comment: surface is not probably a standard uint32_t, see Nicol Bolas's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VkSurfaceKHR` is a non-dispatchable handle. Which, by Vulkan's definitions, is a 64-bit integer. And therefore it must have 8-byte alignment.

When structures are being laid out, the compiler will ensure that each member gets the alignment that the type requires. If `surface` had come immediately after `flags`, it would not have 8-byte alignment. Thus, the compiler inserts 4 bytes of padding between the two.

Comment: The issue is that `flags` is taking up 8 bytes.

Comment: @rhynodegreat: No, it isn't. It takes up 4 bytes. Following it are four *unusued bytes*, so that the next field can be 8-byte aligned.

Comment: Ah, so the padding is added because the next field is 8 bytes and needs to be aligned. Same with `queueFamilyIndexCount`, which is followed by a pointer.

Comment: Technically there is no "padding", just alignment.  `surface` is aligned at a multiple of 8 bytes because it's a 64 bit value.  If you inserted another uint32_t between `flags` and `surface`, the offset to `surface` would remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

All type have a size `sizeof(T)`, and an alignment requirement `alignof(T)`. Instances of it always need to be laid out in memory at addresses that are multiple of `alignof(T)`.

In a struct, the compiler automatically inserts *padding* between the elements such that this requirement is fulfilled for all its elements, relative to the start address of the struct (i.e. for the `offsetof` values). This is empty space between subsequent struct elements.

It also sets the `alignof` of the whole struct, such that all its elements will be correctly aligned in memory. For example on a typical 64 bit platform:

```
struct A {
    char c;    // sizeof(char) == 1; alignof(char) == 1
    int* ptr;  // sizeof(char) == 8; alignof(char) == 8
}
```

Pointers have a size of 8 byte (64 bit), and also an alignment requirement of 8 byte. In this struct there will be 7 bytes of padding between `c` and `ptr`, such that `offsetof(A, c) == 0` and `offsetof(A, ptr) == 8`. And `alignof(A) == 8`. Whenever an instance `A a` is created (on stack or on heap), `&a % 8 == 0`, and so `&(a.ptr) % 8 == 0`.

---

This is done because some CPU instructions (for example SIMD vector instructions) require their operands to be aligned at word boundaries, i.e. multiples of 8 (or 4 for 32 bit) in memory. Without the proper alignment these instructions could not be directly used and the program would become slower.

---

In this example `VkSurfaceKHR` and `pQueueFamilyIndices` are pointers with `alignof == 8`.

Comment: you can use the empty space